# How do you replace \T\ in a Mirth Transformer script?

Tags: mirth

An HL7 message is encoded using a few special characters `|^&~` However sometimes test names in OBR.4 contain the `&` character and per HL7 standards, it should be encoded as `\T\` and replaced with `&` by the parser. Unfortunately `\T` represents a `tab` character in RegEx and I am unable to formulate an expression that can transform `Vitamin B12 \T\ Folate` to `Vitamin B12 & Folate`.

Tried to use

```
var value = msg['OBR']['OBR.4'][OBR.4.2]; // returns "Vitamin B12 \T\ Folate"
value = value.replace(/\\T\\/g, value)
```

But the above throws the exception `TypeError: INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: An invalid or illegal XML character is specified.`.

Does the replace RegEx expression need to be formulated in a different way for this to work in Mirth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to ensure the string is a `JavaScript` string and not a `Java` string. Here is a function I ended up creating that works

```
function _replaceHL7EncodedCharacters(value) {
        value = value.toString(); // convert to Javascript string
        value = value.replace(/\\T\\/g, '&');
        value = value.replace(/\\R\\/g, '~');
        value = value.replace(/\\E\\/g, '\\');
        value = value.replace(/\\F\\/g, '|');
        value = value.replace(/\\S\\/g, '^');

        return value;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have u tried to use this instead?

```js
value = value.replace(/T/g, "&");
```

as already the returned value

> "Vitamin B12 \T\ Folate"

is interpreted as

> "Vitamin B12 T Folate"

if it works, you will also need to handle this in a way where you don't replace any other unneeded "T".